# How can I set my own ProgressDialog loading image?

Tags: android, progressdialog, animated-gif

I have animated gif image and when i try to use it in ProgressDialog it wont show.

```
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.loading);
    dialog.setTitle("Loading");
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.show();
```

What I`m doing wrong? How can I set my own loading image?

Comment: There's no support for GIF animation in android AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default loading image is not a gif image it's a combination of two images and then animating it around. view the source code it may help you in res.drawable/progress_large.xml of android.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's too late,but i have same question with you. And then i find the solution in this [GitHub Code Repository](http://github.com/ttasterisco/CustomProgressDialogExample) 
And then here what i'am doing

1. Android can't be automatically load gif so you must split your gif
   image into images. You can [use this site](http://ezgif.com/split) to split your Gif. Copy split gif image into your drawable folder.
2. Create [custom progress dialog](https://github.com/ttasterisco/CustomProgressDialogExample/blob/master/src/com/kbs/code/MyCustomProgressDialog.java) and [custom layout](https://github.com/ttasterisco/CustomProgressDialogExample/blob/master/res/layout/view_custom_progress_dialog.xml).
3. Create [custom progress animation](https://github.com/ttasterisco/CustomProgressDialogExample/blob/master/res/drawable/custom_progress_dialog_animation.xml) and then edit soruce image. and then change duration like what you want.
4. Change your code into like this

   `ProgressDialog dialog = new MyCustomProgressDialog.ctor(this);
   dialog.show();`
5. and than your loading image has been change.

That code just show gif image, if you want settitle and setimage just change custom progress dialog and custom layout

Comment: Hi guys, in my current project i'm not longer use that method. Now i'm use library from github, and [here](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) the link, it's more simple, you just config in your layout and set your gif into that's layout and boom you have gif in your apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **custom dialog** instead of using the default ProgressDialog.
Set images according to your need.

Comment: Using custom dialog I cannot display animated gif. :(

Comment: how can i develope custome dialog with image rotation provide some code for me